# Nginx redirect old urls to new site

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

We have migrated an old site and while the domain remains the same, there are hundreds of old URLs from the old site that have SEO value that we want to keep and redirect to the new site.

- The new site runs on `https://www.mysite.co.uk` / `https://mysite.co.uk`
- The old links that we want to redirect are of the format `https://[language_code].mysite.co.uk/[page]`

So for example `https://it.mysite.co.uk/banana` should redirect to `https://mysite.co.uk/it/foo/bar/banana`

I'm thinking i need to create a extra server block that will handle `*.mysite.co.uk` (after the server block that serves `server_name mysite.co.uk www.mysite.co.uk` so that urls with `www` are not caught by it) and redirect using regex, something like:

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;

  server_name *.mysite.co.uk;
  rewrite ... permanent;
}
```

I have no idea how to handle that rewrite though, and also, will i have to generate SSL certificates for all those locales subdomains or will the redirect happen before the need to load the certificate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These language subdomains will need a valid certificate in order for the client's browser to accept the redirection to your new website. As they are under the same main domain, you could use a wildcard certificate.

The regular expression `server_name` can be used to extract the language code from the host name so that it can be used to construct the new URL.

For example:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name ~^(?<lang>..)\.example\.com$;

    ssl_certificate ...;
    ssl_certificate_key ...;

    return 301 $scheme://example.com/$lang/foo/bar$request_uri;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) for details.